# codeigniter redirct function error

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter. I did the sql query to insert the data into the database.my query is running perfectly and is shown in the database table.

But i want to display message if my data is inserted into the table(like data inserted successfully).

here is my controller code:

```
public function insert(){

        $post=$this->input->post();
        unset($post['submit']);
       if($this->testimonial_model->insert_testimonial($post))
       {
           $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback',"Data inserted successfully.");
           $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class','alert-success');
       }else{
           $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback',"failed to add, Please Try again");
           $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class','alert-danger');
       }
       return redirect('testimonial_edit');

    }
```

here is my model code:

```
public function insert_testimonial($insert){
        return $this->db->insert('testimonial',$insert);
    }
```

Here is my view code and my view file name is testimonial_edit

```
<?php 
         if($feedback=$this->session->flashdata('feedback')):
             $feedback_class=$this->session->flashdata('feedback_class');
         ?>
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <div class="alert alert-dismissable <?php $feedback_class?>">
                 <?php $feedback?>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
         <?php
         endif;
         ?>
```

Below this code my form code is there.

After filling form when i clicked on submit button the data is successfully inserted but it showing following error

> 404 Page Not Found
>      The page you requested was not found.

and url of this error page is

```
http://localhost/lalcoresidency/testimonials/dashbord
```

Please help me to find out the solution

Comment: Check `dashbord` or `dashboard` ?

Comment: it's basically a routing problem , do check your routes and match the error url if it's there or not.

Comment: nana its redirct but not showing the message

Comment: check controller file name has first letter only upper case same with class. And you don't need to use return with redirect.

Comment: @nushrat  change your `return redirect()` to : `$this->load->view('testimonial_edit');`  because `testimonial_edit` is not a route it's a view

Comment: @Arsh flashdata with codeigniter only works when use redirect.

Comment: @wolfgang1983  yeah she have to change that thing from flashdata to $data array and pass the message to the view , and the problem to me seems fully that the testimonial_edit route does not exist , it's just a view and she is trying to redirect to that route , and it's giving 404 error and deos not show anything,

Comment: @nushrat Post your routes as well , so we can take a look at them and clear my doubts

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: views/testimonial_edit.php

Line Number: 142

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: views/testimonial_edit.php

Line Number: 142  this error showing now when i change it $this->load->view('testimonial_edit');

Comment: @nushrat post complete code of your routes and testimonial_edit.php file

Comment: @nushrat i cannot see result variable in your view code that you have added in question .

Comment: Arsh i am confused what are you saying

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112381/discussion-between-arsh-and-nushrat).

Comment: Is the route you are trying to get inside the routes folder? and does that route direct to an existing controller and function?

Answer (score 3):

You can't redirect to a view file, so try adding a method to the controller which simply loads the view; then redirect to that method:

```
public function insert(){

    $post=$this->input->post();
    unset($post['submit']);
    if($this->testimonial_model->insert_testimonial($post))
    {
       $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback',"Data inserted successfully.");
       $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class','alert-success');
   }else{
       $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback',"failed to add, Please Try again");
       $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class','alert-danger');
   }
   redirect('current_controller_name/testimonial_edit');

}
/* add this function that you can redirect to, 
and which will load the view file of the same name */
function testimonial_edit(){
    $this->load->view('testimonial_edit');
}
```

As for your success message not displaying, try:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('feedback')){ ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="alert alert-dismissable <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('feedback_class'); ?>">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('feedback'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: yes mudshark ..by doing this its working perfectly but ..successfull msg is not showing

Comment: this is excactly a problem.

Comment: You're welcome @nushrat! Kindly mark my answer as having solved your problem please :-)

Comment: Hi @nushrat, As you wrote "*..Thanx alot mudshark*". So, kindly correct this answer. As it will help other user to find this answer easily.

Comment: Thanks. But, That's you **up-voted** the answer. **Not selected** the answer. For selecting the appropriate answer, please have a look here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work @nushrat And, please do for all 12 questions you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:-

```
  public function insert(){
          $this->load->library('session');
            $post=$this->input->post();
            unset($post['submit']);
           if($this->testimonial_model->insert_testimonial($post))
           {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback',"Data inserted successfully.");
               $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class','alert-success');
           }else{
               $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback',"failed to add, Please Try again");
               $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback_class','alert-danger');
           }

 echo ($this->session->flashdata('feedback_class')) ? $this->session->flashdata('feedback_class') : '';

 echo ($this->session->flashdata('feedback')) ? $this->session->flashdata('feedback') : '';

die;

            redirect(base_url('testimonial_edit'));

        }
```

Comment: Again check my updated code. Firstly we will sure , flashdata value get or not

Comment: now it showing blank and url is..  http://localhost/lalcoresidency/testimonials/insert

Comment: @AnshuPratapYadav remove the `die;`

Comment: first clear what real problem, Redirection or session msg?

Comment: @AnshuPratapYadav  , it was  a message problem now , her if condition is not correct check it's code

Comment: use 'public' before function as public function  testimonial_edit()

Comment: nushrat bolo na kya huaa?

Comment: don't forget to write the controller name in redirection, this is a good practice.

Comment: nushrat reply plz. @

Answer (score 0):

Add **url** helper in config file **helper** array

like `$config['helper']=array("url");`